# How to use select input to subset a dataframe in r shiny?

Tags: r, select, input, shiny

I am trying to subset a dataframe according to variables of a column

However, I get an error saying that

Error in $<-.data.frame: replacement has 1 row, data has 0

Below is a part of my code.

UI

```
selectInput("avpname",
            "Select AVP:",
             c(unique(as.character(IncidentTickets$RequestorAVP))))
```

server

```
limitDateRange <- reactive({
NumberOfIncidentTickets <- subset(NumberOfIncidentTickets, RequestorAVP == input$avpname)
})
```

it is a part of my long code.

I tested with having

```
NumberOfIncidentTickets <- subset(NumberOfIncidentTickets, RequestorAVP == 'Students')
```

it worked fine so I am assuming that input$avpname is somehow I am using in a wrong way.

I will appreciate for help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit difficult to pinpoint why your code is not working with these little code snippets. I used them to construct a working example.

```
IncidentTickets = data.frame(RequestorAVP=c(1,2,3,4))
NumberOfIncidentTickets = data.frame(RequestorAVP=c(1,2,3,4))


library(shiny)
library(DT)
ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    selectInput("avpname",
                "Select AVP:",
                c(unique(as.character(IncidentTickets$RequestorAVP)))),
    DT::dataTableOutput("table")
  )
)

server <- function(input,output)
{

  limitDateRange <- reactive({
    NumberOfIncidentTickets <- subset(NumberOfIncidentTickets, RequestorAVP == input$avpname)
  })

  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(
    limitDateRange()
  )
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. I tried this and works fine but I do not know why it doesn't work with all my codes together.

Comment: Maybe add some print() statements within your code, and look what happens in your console. Are all the variables as expected, are there no NULL's etc. Maybe that can help you trace your bug.

Comment: Thanks I will try print() to see if I can trace better!